# corodoa build fails framework/gen/org/apache/cordova/R.java: Permission denied

Tags: cordova

I installed cordova and it was working fine with both ios and android paltform. 
but recently it started failing with weard errors , I stareted removing >null in create script to read errors and i show above error.
I tried using sudo for creating prject but still getting sdame error.
later I changed permission for all  files under  `.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.0.0/framework/gen`

and the error got resolved but a next error

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/sachinsharma/Desktop/sachin/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:650: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/sachinsharma/Desktop/sachin/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:702: Failed to create BuildConfig class

Total time: 0 seconds
An unexpected error occurred: ant jar exited with 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are still some more places to change permission so i did it on whole folder recursively with this command.

sudo chown -R sachinsharma ~/.cordova

and all problem gone